# Documentation generator for Testcomplete

Tags: testcomplete

What are the best practices for using/selecting documentation generation tool for Testcomplete? e.g. JSDoc, Natural Docs, YUIDoc etc.

Are there any that best fit for TC? and why?

Comment: Currently I am using a custom tool for doing the other way: Generating comments from written tests that have to be automated by me using TestComplete. Your question might fit better here btw.: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the JSDoc plugin for Grunt (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-jsdoc) and it works great. The JSDoc plugin comes with docstrap. This means you can use all the Docstrap templates as shown here (http://terryweiss.github.io/docstrap/themes/united/), rather than the plain default one that comes with JSDoc. The Docstrap template also adds search functionality to your documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use JSDoc and it fits perfectly TestComplete scripts.
Haven't tried the others but there's nothing I need and JSDoc doesn't provide.